# Why default MySql string matching is case insensitive?

Tags: mysql

```
select * from some_table where col = 'text';
```

Why results will be case insensitive unlike all popular programming languages?

Comment: you can read about it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 3):

The case sensitivity depends on the collation of the fields/values in question.
MySQL has many different collations, but they mostly end with either `_ci` for case insensitive or `_cs` for case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Default is Case insensitive, However to make a case sensitive query, you can use:-

```
SELECT *  FROM `some_table` WHERE BINARY `col` = 'text';
```

or If you want a column always to be treated in case-sensitive fashion, declare it with a case sensitive or binary collation.

Comment: This answer is for question - "How to make a case sensitive string matching query?".